# JavaEE Batch Processing Start Process

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, batch-processing

I want to go throw javaee batch processing, so I create a simple web application where I want to expose a get method for starting a job.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response helloWorld() {
    Hello hello = new Hello();
    hello.setMessage("Hello World");

    JobOperator jobOperator = getJobOperator();
    Long executionId = jobOperator.start("myJob", new Properties());
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobOperator.getJobExecution(executionId);

    System.out.println(jobExecution.getBatchStatus());

    return Response.ok(hello).build();
```

The rest service is working fine, I am running it on an intellij idea community edition and I am using maven plugin for running it on a tomcat server.

The problem is that the BatchRuntime.getJobOperator() is always returning null. I tried to use only the javaee-api dependecy, but then the BatchRuntime class is not found. After that I added **javax.batch-api** dependency and after that the class **BatchRuntime** was found, but **getJobOperator()** always return null.

Please tell me how can I run a job in order to get more familiarized with batch processing in javaee. I have looked over tutorials, git repo, but I didn't there is no clear way for how to run a xml job.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is not a full Java EE server, and does not include JBatch. You should use an application server that is Java EE compliant, e.g. Glassfish/Payara, TomEE, or Wildfly.

Comment: I had added separate dependencies for JBatch, but I could try the same scenario with another java ee server